# Find the deleted records in the Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Recently faced issues with how to know about deleted records from table.

I try to explain my question. I have a table like below :

**Table Employee**

```
Emp No                   Employee Name
unique Guid1             John Smith
unique Guid2             Tom 
unique Guid3             Jenny
unique Guid4             Paul
unique Guid5             Scott
```

There are millions of records in the database and  multiple developers are working on the database.

If Developer A deleted  `Emp No unique Guid1` and `unique Guid4`, Developer B wants to know which records are deleted recently.
I know that Sql server 2008 R2 logs the transaction, but I didn't find an exact way to know these records.

Please help me!!! Thanks

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database from before the delete?

Comment: Do you actually want to recover the deleted records? or you just want Developer B to know what records has been deleted ?

Comment: You'll have to store the information somewhere.

Comment: @M.Ali Just want Developer B to know what records has been deleted

Comment: @DavidG but after every deletion , we need to restore the database or we can maintain audit trails, but I want to use transaction log data.

Comment: @DanBracuk No such mechanism , where I can look in to transaction log for deleted records

Comment: To look into transaction log, you will need to get help from some kind of third-party tool like ApexSQL or Red-Gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several options

1. **Modify the schema** (table definiation) to include fields like "isDeleted", "deletedOn", "deletedBy" and set these fields when "deleting" instead og actually deleteing the records. All "selects" from this table must then when altered to include this new logic
2. **Use a trigger** to listen to deletes and copy the data onto a "auditing" table.
3. **[Snapshot Backups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189548(v=sql.105).aspx)**

What to use really depends on the use case

Answer (score 2):

Change tracking feature is available for SQL Server 2008. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would suggest creating an After Delete trigger on your table and log any deletes in that table into a log table , I wont be to keen on adding new columns to your existing table, like deleted , deleted by etc, since you have mentioned you have millions of rows, Why bother with millions of records only deal with the deleted ones.

Create a table to keep the logs of deleted records say `Employee_Audit` and a trigger would look something like this....

### Log Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Audit
 ( Emp_GUID     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   Date_deleted DATETIME,
   Deleted_By   nvarchar(128)
 );
GO
```

### Trigger Definition

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_log_deletes
ON Employee
AFTER DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO Employee_Audit (Emp_GUID, Date_deleted, Deleted_By)
  SELECT [GUID] , GETDATE() , SUSER_SNAME() 
  FROM deleted 
END
```